# How do I add data to a JList via user input captured by JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have a JButton named 'course' that has an actionListener that populates a JOptionPane asking the user to enter a course name. I'm trying to add the course name to the JList to display after the add course action is completed. I've tried classList.add(input) in the actionListener method but it's not working. Any help is appreciated. This is for class so tips are appreciated; I'm not after full code. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LabEleven extends JFrame{

    public LabEleven(){
String[] list = {"Math", "\nComputer", "\nPhysics", "\nChemistry"}; // create array     of String data for JList
JList<String> classList = new JList<String> (list); // create JList to pass to     JPanel

JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 2, 2));
p1.add(classList);
p1.setBackground(Color.white);

JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 2, 2));


// add "add course" button and attach action listener
JButton course = new JButton("Add Course");
course.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter another course"));

    } // end actionPerformed

}); // end addActionListener

// add "close" button and attach action listener
JButton close = new JButton("Close");
close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);

    } // end actionPerformed

}); // end addActionListener


p2.add(course);
p2.add(close);


add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

} // end LabEleven constructor

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new LabEleven();
    frame.setSize(400, 420);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

} // end main method

} // end LabEleven class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `ListModel` when dealing with the `JList`, for example, an easily manageable `DefaultListModel`. You can then use the method [`DefaultListModel.addElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29) for dynamic population of the list.

You first need to initialize your list with the model

```
final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList jList = new JList(model);
// you can loop to populate the model here with your default list[] data
```

After doing that, you can call `model.addElement(input)` in your listener

---

See more at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and maybe focus on the section using models.

Also see the API for [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) for more available methods.

Comment: Thank you, that worked although it asked that I declare the dlm as Final. I'll do some reading to see why that is. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also check out some of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=local%20va#q=local%20variable%20needs%20to%20be%20declared%20final)

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating
Manipulating JList after declaring It's model can be very effective.